# How to handle Internal Server Error in REST API using JAVA?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, exception

I have create a class to handle runtime exception throws during service call and my code is

```
@Override
public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException exception) {
    Response response=exception.getResponse();
    if(response.getStatus()==400)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Invalid data format. Please enter the data in xml format").build();
    else if(response.getStatus()==403)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("You are not authorize to access this resource").build();
    else if(response.getStatus()==500)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Internal server error has occured.Please check wheather you have passed valid data or not").build();
    else if(response.getStatus()==404)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Invalid url. Please enter a valid url").build();
    else if(response.getStatus()==415)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE).entity("Invalid media type. Please select the correct media type").build();
    else if(response.getStatus()==503)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).entity("Server is not available. Please try after some time").build();
    else
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("").build();
}
```

my problem is that it handles all the other exception throws during service calls except INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. Please help me how to handle INTERNAL SERVER ERROR during run time in REST.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to know is their any wrong in my question so that others give me -ve marks. Those who given -ve marks is really knows the solution or simply given it after seen it. If they knows the solution so just answer me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what webserver you are using, but as long as it adheres to `JEE specs` you could simply handle it in your `web.xml`:

> <error-page>
>       <error-code>500</error-code>
>       <location>/path/to/myErrorPage.html</location>
>   </error-page>

Comment: **dot_SpOt** thanks for your comment but I want to know how to handle in REST to show client INTERNAL SERVER ERROR message. My code works fine for all the others exception but not with INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Comment: I am not sure if you are refering to any third party lib by `REST`. But in itself `REST` is an abbreviation for `Representational State Transfer` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), which in itself is a term, but no product.