# How to Handle 500 internal error while mapping JSON to POJO If one of attribute of POJO class is empty

Tags: java, rest

Hi I am working on Rest API written in java and have come through the below doubt.

I have already written the code which takes post data and maps to pojo class and sends back the data in JSON form.

Correct Format:-

```
{
    "Name":"Rahul",
    "Address":"Mumbai",
    "Age": 27
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "Pkid":"1",
    "Name":"Rahul",
    "Address":"Mumbai",
    "Age": 27
}
```

But when I am passing empty value to one of the attribute I am getting 500 internal error can someone help me how to handle it and return the value in json format after handling it:

```
{
    "Name":,
    "Address":"Mumbai",
    "Age": 27
}
```

Output:

```
500 Internal error
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines of your source code? The stack trace you see probably gives you a detailed answer of what is going on, so please post that too.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502993/how-to-handle-internal-server-error-in-rest-api-using-java

Comment: If you want to pass empty value don not use that attribute at all, JSON which you have used is invalid. Either use `{ "Name":"", "Address":"Mumbai" ,"Age": 27 }` or `{"Address":"Mumbai", "Age": 27 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson library and set the below property while creating object.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Add the below maven dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

You can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608996/7726319) also.

EDIT 1:
Deserialize your jsonObject as :

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,POJO.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, use a json validator. it seems that you have a missing comma.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

And also it is helpful to share corresponding code, and retrieved exception etc.

Answer (score 0):

***Understanding:*** you are trying to store an object and return the object details along with the primary key id generated
Following are two approaches for this:

***1. Custom de-serializer with Jackson***:
I would prefer this method because it provides you with additional security. In the current  scenario, you are exposed to cross-site scripting attacks
Using a custom de-serializer along with [Jsoup api](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/overview-summary.html) or [Antisamy](https://owasp.org/www-project-antisamy/) to filter the data would help you prevent XSS and also include null values.

You need to add your custom de-serializer to your pojo using:

```
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    public class User {
       private String id;

       private String name;
      // standard getters and setters
    }
```

***2. Using Jackson annotation:***

```
public class User {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String id;

    private String name;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```